# Why does shifting this bit evalue to 51

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm currently learning for a C++ examn. One of the questions in the practice examn is:

What is the output of this statement.

```
cout <<(11>>1)<<1<<endl;
```

As I see it. 11 holds the binary equivalent of

```
1011.
```

Shifting this binary number with 1 bit to the right makes it:

```
0101
```

Then shifting THAT number one to the left makes it

```
1010
```

Which evaluates to 10.

However, by running the same statement in my compiler it says the number evaluates to 51. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Did you try `cout <<((11>>1)<<1)<<endl;` ?

Comment: It's not 51, it's a 5 followed by a 1.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers everyone! I do find it pretty dissapointing that people would downvote this question. I just wanted to learn

Comment: I do hope that you learn not to write such code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is due to operator overloading.

```
cout <<(11>>1)<<1<<endl;
//   ^ output operator
//        ^ right shift
//            ^ output operator
```

If you were to change the code to this, then your answer would be correct:

```
cout << ((11>>1) << 1) <<endl;
// brackets force left shift operator instead of output
```

Answer (score 6):

`cout << (11>>1) << 1 << endl;`

becomes

`cout << 5 << 1 <<endl;`

The streaming meaning of `<<` takes precedence over the shifting meaning. Therefore it prints a 5 followed by a 1.

Comment: "The streaming meaning of `<<` takes precedence over the shifting meaning." It's actually a result of [the syntacic associativity of `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). If you change `cout` to a numeric object, you'll still end up with something like `7 << (11>>1) << 1 == (7 << (11>>1)) << 1;`

Answer (score 4):

```
int a = (11>>1);
int b = 1;
cout << a << b;
```

Clear?